# Check Radio Buttons by Class

Tags: jquery, radio-button, checked

```js
$(".test").each(function(i) {
  this.checked = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio" class="test" id="tr1" />
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio" class="radio" id="tr2" />


<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio" class="radio2" id="tr3" />
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio" class="test" id="tr4" />
<button class="button">Click</button>
```

I have two sets of radio buttons and I would like to have the class "test" ticked by default.

How would I go about doing this with radio buttons as we can now only tick one radio button

Comment: They all have the same name.  Only one of those can be selected at any given time, since they are radios.

Comment: Also as a small side note, you do not need the each for your logic.  You can just do `$('.test').prop('checked', true)`

Comment: well, that was silly of me. Thanks @Taplar. Also, thanks for the prop code!

Comment: Why not just use `checked` attribute

Comment: @YouneL  what do you mean by that comment?

Comment: @Taplar I mean that he can use `checked` attribute in `tr1` and `tr2` elements to get them checked by default without using JS

Comment: @YouneL  no, they can't.  Not if they all share the same name.  http://jsfiddle.net/ajpsxb17/  Your missing the crux of the issue with this question.

Comment: @Taplar I already note that, and of course he should change the name

Comment: I don't see where you noted that.  All I see is *Why not just use checked attribute*

Comment: @Taplar, I said so, because I already saw your comment and I don't want to repeat.

Comment: In situations like this, I would suggest that it would be better to repeat, if you are going to make an additional statement that relies on another statement happening.  As you can see from this exchange, not doing can cause confusion and makes it look like other points towards the question are being disregarded by your statement.  Primarily the **why not just** reinforces this point of view, suggesting this is the only thing that needs to change.

Comment: I used the above code, because "checked" didn't work. This didn't work because I used the same name. I have now ditched the jquery and am just using "checked". Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name the two sets differently because if they are all named `radio` only one of them can be checked at a time. Simply rename the second set to something else like `radio2` in my example below and then the sets will work independent of each other.

```js
$(".test").each(function(i) {
  this.checked = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio" class="test" id="tr1" />
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio" class="radio" id="tr2" />


<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio2" class="radio2" id="tr3" />
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio2" class="test" id="tr4" />
<button class="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

By [**definition**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#radio-button-state-(type%3Dradio)), radio buttons are a group of `<input>` elements sharing the same `name` with the out-of-the-box behavior that when one of them is selected they give the containing `<form>` namespace defined by their common `name` the value of the selected one and automatically deselect any other radio button with same `name`.

It has been specifically designed for this use-case (where from multiple options users are allowed to pick one).

If your scenario requires to enable users to select more than one, either

- use different `name` attributes,
- use `<input type="checkbox">`s
- use `<select>` elements with `multiple="true"`

  ---

To sum it up: no matter what you do, no decent browser will allow you to select more than one `<input type="radio">` with the same `name` in the same `<form>` element. By any method. And, even if it would have theoretically been possible, trying to get the value of that namespace would have failed.

Radio buttons are like Highlanders: *"There can be only one"*.